# How to change the height of a progressbar in newer versions of android?

Tags: android, progress-bar

How can I change the height of a horizontal Progress Bar in Android. I have seen that in some earlier versions (ex. Gingerbread) that I can just set attributes of minHeight and maxHeight to the same value, that value being the desired height. But for some reason in Jelly Bean and possibly Ice Cream Sandwich, this method is not working for setting the height via XML (preferred for this situation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create dimens file in values folder according the screen size (hdpi, xhdpi...) or version (11, 12,...) and etc' 
and set there value inside

i.e.

1.create in values-hdpi folder : 8dp

2.create in values-xhdpi folder:  10dp

hope this help you